# Linq query syntax to select latest version from database

Tags: sql, linq

I have a products table (Id, ProductsId, CreatedDate, Status). Single productId can have multiple entries and the status column can have value 1 or 2. I need the LINQ query syntax to select all the columns from products table with date filter and  a condition that each selected product is the latest based on CreatedDate and each product should only have status value 1 until the filtered date.

I have tried the following sql query but cannot convert it to linq query syntax:

```
SELECT p1.*
from "Products" as p1
WHERE p1."CreatedDate" = (SELECT max(p2."CreatedDate" )
                          FROM "Products" as p1
                          WHERE p1."ProductId" = p2."ProductId" and mcs."Status" = 1)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have a look at the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.

Comment: I have tried the following sql query but cannot convert it to linq query syntax.   SELECT p1.* from "Products" as p1 
   WHERE p1."CreatedDate" =(SELECT max(p2."CreatedDate" ) FROM "Products" as p1 WHERE p1."ProductId" = p2."ProductId" and mcs."Status" = 1);

Comment: Your SQL query mixes up p1 and p2 table aliases.